# Set checkbox checked with jquery only to child element

Tags: jquery

How to set checkbox=checked with jquery to child element only? I have the following html code

```
<div id="mon">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="mon_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="mon_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
<div id="tue">
  <span>Tue</span>
  <input type="text" class="start" name="tue_start" placeholder="Start" value="">
  <input type="text" class="end" name="tue_end" placeholder="End" value="">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="h24" value="1">24hrs</label>
</div>
```

I tried the following code, but it always changed the checkbox of div #mon:

```
$('#mon, #tue input').on('change', function(){
  if ($(this).find('.start').val() == '00:00' && $(this).find('.end').val() == '24:00'){
      $(this).find('.h24').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
      $(this).find('.h24').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `#mon, #tue input` selects the `#mon` DIV and all the inputs inside `#tue`. But `$(this).find()` will not work when `this` is an input, because they're not containers.

You should just use `$("#mon, #tue"). The`change`event will bubble up from all the inputs in the DIV, and then you can select other elements within the DIV using`$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Quite close indeed! Use the following selector instead of `'#mon, #tue input'`

```
'#mon input, #tue input'
```